# request and login a site using curl

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, curl

I want to check whether a user has any notification of facebook or not.. to do that I thought of curl, but the user have to put his login detail. I wonder is there any better way to do it? The weak point of curl method is that the users will receive warning email because someone loggin from different locality.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook has a security witch prevent you to access the site by cURL.

You better create a facebook application, by using the notification API : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/notifications